# Touch screen and external monitor: a ZenBook Duo - like setup?

Tags: drivers, display, monitors, steam, touch-screen

I am using the Steam Deck as a daily driver since some time and i am pretty happy with it. If someone is not familiar, this is a pretty beefy (for normal tasks) handheld linux PC.

I configured SteamOS (which is basically arch based) and I am happy with it. I am currently using an external display and not using the built in touch screen.

As I was looking at the ZenBook Duo with its touch screen below the main one i was thinking if there is something that allows me to set up the native touch screen of the Steam Deck as the ZenBook Duo screen.